# How to filter columns in Tk treeview based on column value?

Tags: python, tkinter

just started learning python/tkinter and already ran into a problem. I'm trying to open excel file in treeview which works perfect, now I found another script online which applies a drop menu to filter based on column values. But I'm failing to incorporate into mine, can anyone help please?

Current Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog
import pandas as pd
win = Tk()
win.geometry("700x350")
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('clam')

frame = Frame(win)
frame.pack(pady=20)


def open_file():
    global df
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Open a File")

if filename:
    try:
        filename = r"{}".format(filename)
        df = pd.read_excel(filename)
    except ValueError:
        label.config(text="File could not be opened")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        label.config(text="File Not Found")

clear_treeview()

tree["column"] = list(df.columns)
tree["show"] = "headings"

for col in tree["column"]:
    tree.heading(col, text=col)
    tree.column("#1", anchor="center", width=200)
    tree.column("#2", anchor="center", width=150)
    tree.column("#3", anchor="center", width=150)
    tree.column("#4", anchor="center", width=150)

df_rows = df.to_numpy().tolist()
for row in df_rows:
    tree.insert("", "end", values=row)

tree.pack()


def clear_treeview():
    tree.delete(*tree.get_children())


tree = ttk.Treeview(frame)

m = Menu(win)
win.config(menu=m)

file_menu = Menu(m, tearoff=False)
m.add_cascade(label="Menu", menu=file_menu)
file_menu.add_command(label="Open Spreadsheet", command=open_file)

label = Label(win, text='')
label.pack(pady=20)

win.mainloop()
```

And code found online for filter:

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import ttk

df = pd.DataFrame({"currency":["EUR","XCD","ARS","CAD"],
               "volume":[400,500,600,700]})


class app(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Python Guides")

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self)
        columns = list(df.columns)
        self.Combo = ttk.Combobox(self, values=list(df["currency"].unique()),state="readonly")
        self.Combo.pack()
        self.Combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.select_currency)
        self.tree["columns"] = columns
        self.tree.pack(expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)

        for i in columns:
            self.tree.column(i, anchor="w")
            self.tree.heading(i, text=i, anchor="w")

        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            self.tree.insert("", "end", text=index, values=list(row))

    def select_currency(self,event=None):
        self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children())
        for index, row in df.loc[df["currency"].eq(self.Combo.get())].iterrows():
            self.tree.insert("", "end", text=index, values=list(row))

ws = app()
ws.mainloop()
```

[Example of table to be imported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btFbd.jpg), [How it's imported in treeview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTOLl.jpg),
[Example of drop menu filter with values from Column "currency"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HMho.jpg)

Comment: While posting the code, stackoverflow was asking me to indent x4 messed up somewhere, apologies.

Comment: Other than the indentation issue, your code does not have any *dropdown* widget and *filtering* code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know which column you want to populate with values so I left it as a Combobox selector, Selecting field will populate the values Combobox.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog
import pandas as pd

win = Tk()
win.geometry("700x350")
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('clam')

frame = Frame(win)
frame.pack(pady=20)
filename = None


def open_file():
    global df
    global filename
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Open a File")

    if filename:
        try:
            filename = r"{}".format(filename)
            df = pd.read_excel(filename)
        except ValueError:
            label.config(text="File could not be opened")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            label.config(text="File Not Found")

    def create_column_combox():  # Creating the select field and value Combobox
        def populate_values_combo(e=None):  # populate values combobox with unique column values
            state = 'normal'
            combo_values = []
            if col_combo.get() == 'All':  # if option All selected
                state = 'disabled'  # disabling the option to select values
                select_value()
            else:
                combo_values = ['All'] + df[col_combo.get()].unique().tolist()  # adding option All to values

            col_values_combo.config(values=combo_values, state=state)

        def select_value(e=None):  # cleaning tree and populating with df values
            tree.delete(*tree.get_children())
            if col_combo.get() == 'All' or col_values_combo.get() == 'All':  # if All selected as column or value
                col_values_combo.current(0)  # setting values to All
                [tree.insert("", "end", text=str(index), values=list(row)) for index, row in df.iterrows()]
            else:
                for index, row in df.loc[df[col_combo.get()].eq(col_values_combo.get())].iterrows():
                    tree.insert("", "end", text=index, values=list(row))

        columns = ['All'] + list(df.columns)  # Adding option All to list of columns
        column_combo_label = Label(frame, text='Select field')
        column_combo_label.pack()
        col_combo = ttk.Combobox(frame, values=columns, state='readonly')
        col_combo.pack()
        col_combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", populate_values_combo)
        volume_combo_label = Label(frame, text='Select value')
        volume_combo_label.pack()
        col_values_combo = ttk.Combobox(frame, state='disabled')
        col_values_combo.pack()
        col_values_combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", select_value)

    create_column_combox()
    clear_treeview()

    tree["column"] = list(df.columns)
    tree["show"] = "headings"

    for col in tree["column"]:
        tree.heading(col, text=col)
        tree.column("#1", anchor="center", width=200)
        tree.column("#2", anchor="center", width=150)
        tree.column("#3", anchor="center", width=150)
        tree.column("#4", anchor="center", width=150)

    df_rows = df.to_numpy().tolist()
    for row in df_rows:
        tree.insert("", "end", values=row)

    tree.pack()


def clear_treeview():
    tree.delete(*tree.get_children())


tree = ttk.Treeview(frame)

m = Menu(win)
win.config(menu=m)

file_menu = Menu(m, tearoff=False)
m.add_cascade(label="Menu", menu=file_menu)
file_menu.add_command(label="Open Spreadsheet", command=open_file)

label = Label(win, text='')
label.pack(pady=20)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: You sir are a magician! Thank you so much for this

Comment: One quick question, is it possible when filterling by Login to have the option Select All to switch back to entire tree view?

Comment: It possible but will require some modifications, like adding first option as 'All' and quering about the selection and modify the function with if to select different output.I'm currently not in front of my computer so I won't be able to show how.

Comment: I'm more than happy to wait until you can :) You already helped me with more than I asked. The Select All, and if Select Field could have just "Ownership" & "Login" as options, I will be forever in your depth

Comment: Updated, added a selection option 'All'

Comment: I've just happen to read all of your comment, you just have to replace: columns = ['All'] + list(df.columns) with: columns = ['All', "Ownership", "Login"] will do. It is no different if you choose All to any of the fields, it will display all anyway.

Comment: Works perfectly! Don't know how to thank you enough. I will break down piece by piece to understand the logic to learn my self!

Comment: Is there a way to open an excel automatically instead of using open file dialog?

Comment: replace the 'filedialog.askopenfilename' method with the file full path string